# Angular 10 - Endpoint access works from postman but not from Angular

Tags: angular, angular10

I have a frontend angular application that I am running from **localhost:4200**

I also have a backend api application that I am running from **localhost:8080**

I also have postman running, which I used to test these endpoints before I created the angular frontend.

My issue is **localhost:8080/** works after calling **localhost:8080/sign-in** via postman, but not after calling **localhost:8080/sign-in** by my angular frontend.

I can use the route **localhost:8080/sign-in** via postman, which signs in the user and sets the session cookie.
Here is the result:

**Response:**

```
It returns the user object here as JSON
```

**Header:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    
Access-Control-Expose-Headers   Set-Cookie
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie  session_=RTZCYXOW3ILNKOOZQOZKEC4Y3J3YPOVUGGA6TI46ZLRX5UAWS77O7TGE74ZEFQEOTZLTCKRTCYJJ57OT24KUPPMBPYOXWBZRXF54PGA; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 29 Nov 2020 09:33:43 GMT; Max-Age=604800
Vary    Origin
X-Request-Id    gTCSwvwm4m8oLDqy99fkhqAeWgrddnjl
Date    Sun, 22 Nov 2020 09:33:43 GMT
Content-Length  658
```

Then I have another endpoint: **localhost:8080/** which requires the user to be signed in to access.

**If they are signed in:**

**Response**:

```
“Valid”
```

**Header:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    
Access-Control-Expose-Headers   Set-Cookie
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary    Origin
X-Request-Id    mRy9w40wEKx4zI2h4JuaMAZ2CppbvzHR
Date    Sun, 22 Nov 2020 09:34:47 GMT
Content-Length  8
```

If they are not signed in:

**Response:**

```
"access denied”
```

**Header:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
X-Request-Id: eRQJwPIXQnAOavpgkhobNoJnKgbQmDpE
Date: Sun, 22 Nov 2020 09:36:11 GMT
Content-Length: 18
```

Now from my angular application I am able to call the **localhost:8080/sign-in** endpoint.
This does return the user as a JSON object which is the same as postman.

However I do not think it is setting the cookie so that when I call the **localhost:4200/** endpoint from my angular application it gives the error: [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 1ms] which is the same error I get from postman if I try to access that endpoint while signed out.

I ensured that I called the **localhost:8080/sign-in** before trying **localhost:8080/** while on the angular frontend (to try and have the cookie set first)

Here is my relevant configurations on my backend api:

**This is the session store configuration**

```
store.Options(sessions.Options{
    Path: "/",
    MaxAge:   86400 * 7,
    HttpOnly: false,    
})
```

**This is the middleware configuration**

```
e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
    AllowOrigins:  []string{"http://localhost:4200"},
    AllowHeaders:  []string{echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderAccept, echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowCredentials},
    ExposeHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderSetCookie},
    AllowCredentials: true,
}))
```

Here are my services and components for signing in on the angular frontend:

**auth-http.service.ts**

```
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<Response> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.set('access-control-allow-origin',"http://localhost:4200/");
    headers.set('withCredentials', "true");
  

   
    let result =  this.http.post<any>(`${API_URL}/sign-in`,   { email: email, password: password }, { headers });

    return result;


  }

  test(): Observable<Response> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.set('access-control-allow-origin',"http://localhost:4200/");
    headers.set('withCredentials', "true");
    
    let result =  this.http.get<any>(`${API_URL}/`, { headers });

    return result;

  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserModel> {
 
    this.isLoadingSubject.next(true);

    return this.authHttpService.login(email, password).pipe(

      map((result: Response) => {

        // undefined
        console.log(result.headers)
       
        console.log(result);
        // pass in the auth here
       
  
        return result;
      }),
      //switchMap(() => this.getUserByToken()),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error('err', err); // here
        return of(undefined);
      }),
      finalize(() => this.isLoadingSubject.next(false))
    );
  }

  test(): Observable<any> {
 
    this.isLoadingSubject.next(true);

    return this.authHttpService.test().pipe(

      map((result: Response) => {
        return result;
      }),
      //switchMap(() => this.getUserByToken()),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error('err', err); // here
        return of(undefined);
      }),
      finalize(() => this.isLoadingSubject.next(false))
    );
  }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
  submit() {
    this.hasError = false;
    const loginSubscr = this.authService
      .login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((user: UserModel) => {
        console.log(user);
        if (user) {
          this.router.navigate([this.  returnUrl]);
        } else {
          this.hasError = true;
        }
      });
    this.unsubscribe.push(loginSubscr);
  }

  test() {
       this.hasError = false;
    const loginSubscr = this.authService
      .test()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
       if (res) {
          console.log(res)
        } else {
          this.hasError = true;
        }
      });
this.unsubscribe.push(loginSubscr);
  }
```

For testing the **localhost:8080/** endpoint I just created a test button on the login html component which then calls a test service to see if it can access the **localhost:8080/** endpoint.

Comment: "*However I do not think it is setting the cookie so that when I call the **localhost:4200/ endpoint** from my angular application it gives the error...*" Not sure why you would make a call to localhost:4200 from Angular. No wonder you're getting a 403 status.. or is it a typing error in your question's description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using:

```
  const options = {withCredentials: true, 'access-control-allow-origin': "http://localhost:4200/", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Instead of the other way of setting headers.